# Jmeter - Spline Visualizer

Tags: spline, visualizer

What information does Spline Visualizer graph provide to the user? The generated Spline Visualizer got a huge spike at the start followed by Troughs. Kindly help me to understand what information does it provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might help

"The Spline Visualizer provides a view of all sample times from the
start of the test till the end, regardless of how many samples have
been taken. The spline has 10 points, each representing 10% of the
samples, and connected using spline logic to show a single continuous
line."

From
http://jmeter.512774.n5.nabble.com/usage-of-spline-graph-td528870.html

Comment: Hi ABP,
Thanks for your response. I understand how they generate the graph with 10 points but I fail to understand on what basis the points are chosen. What can we achieve by looking at Spline Visualizer?

Comment: The spline visualizer presents a smooth curve that represents the data from the entire test run. There are 10 points on the curve, each point represents an average of some subset of the sample run. For instance, if your test run has been running for some time, and you have 1000 samples, the first "point" on the curve will represent an average of the first 100 samples, the next will be for the second 100 samples, etc. These points are connected using spline curves, and allow users to see the entire history of the test and how the responsiveness of their application has changed over time.

Comment: Let me know if it answer your question regarding how points are selected. Please mark this answer as useful if this helps you :)

Comment: Hi ABP,
Thanks for the explanation. And sorry I couldn't mark the answer as useful as I require 15 reputations to do so.